# Filtering Records based on minimum of entries for specific date

Tags: sql, sas

I was trying to filter some records and do aggregation based on few fields.I know that summary functions cannot be used in a where clause.Could anyone help me with a small trick to get my desire result.

Please find more details below.

orderno orderdate billdate dealer sku       sof  diff demandqty /n

```
1       18.6.14     18.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 0    100 /n

5       18.6.14     18.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 0    50 /n

5       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    50 /n

7       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    60 /n

7       18.6.14     20.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 2    60 /n

8       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    75 /n

8       18.6.14     20.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 2    75 /n
```

Here for a particular order date,sof,sku combination,I would like to get the total demand qty taking into consideration only the respective first record.

For example,

Date: `18/6/2014 SKU 11131280 SOF 8001` Desired Demand `(100+50+60+75=285)` where diff is `(0,0,1,1)` respectively that is minimum for the orders `1,5,7,8`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should sort `by date,sof,sku,dif` and then sort again by the same key but with a nodupkey option (or do a datstep `by date,sof,sku` and an `if first.sku`) and then sum with a `proc means`.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the dataset first and then use a data step to calculate the total demand (using the FIRST. automatic variable to only pick the first order number).  I've added some extra lines to the source data in order to fully test the code.

```
data have;
input orderno orderdate :ddmmyy8. billdate :ddmmyy8. dealer sku sof diff demandqty;
format orderdate billdate date9.;
datalines;
1       18.6.14     18.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 0    100 
5       18.6.14     18.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 0    50 
5       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    50 
7       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    60 
7       18.6.14     20.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 2    60 
8       18.6.14     19.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 1    75 
8       18.6.14     20.6.14  113999 11131280  8001 2    75 
1       18.6.14     18.6.14  114000 11131290  8002 0    10 
5       18.6.14     18.6.14  114000 11131290  8002 0    20 
1       19.6.14     18.6.14  114000 11131290  8002 0    70 
5       19.6.14     18.6.14  114000 11131290  8002 0    80 
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by orderdate sof sku orderno;
run;

data want (keep=orderdate sof sku tot_demand);
set have;
by orderdate sof sku orderno;
if first.sku then tot_demand=0;
if first.orderno then tot_demand+demandqty;
if last.sku then output;
run;
```